# How can I return more than just a string in an ASP.Net BadRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here is what I would like to do:

```
return BadRequest(new
    {
       ErrorMessage = (string)parameters[1].Value,
       ErrorNumber = (int)parameters[2].Value
    });
```

However BadRequest takes only a string.  Would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Consider this method to return a custom Json response with your Http 400 code.  
 Source: https://gist.github.com/remi/929007

In web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library like this:

```
return BadRequest(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    ErrorMessage = (string)parameters[1].Value,
    ErrorNumber = (int)parameters[2].Value
}));
```